# How to install packages on Linux for Python 2 with pip when Python 3 is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7

I'm trying to install a package for python 2 using pip, however it defaults to installing for python 3. The script I need to run only works in python 2.7, which i do have installed alongside python 3. The pip-2.7 command does not exist, nor pip2. Is there a way besides that to directly install the package? (hexdump, btw if that helps).

Comment: Is python2 on your path? Usually it's just `python`. So you cold run `python -m pip install xxxx`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked if Python2 is installed ?

Did you tried `pip2` command ?

What's the result if you do `which pip` ?

if pip2 or pip2.7 don't work, you can try `/usr/bin/pip2` or `/usr/bin/pip2.7`